# Xamarin: connect_timeout expired

Tags: xamarin.forms, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I hope you are fine,
I'm having an hard time in my xamarin app, trying to connect it to MySQL, but the error "connect_timout expired" always occured. I try all the tutorial i found, i increase the timeout un my MySQL workbrench...but it doesnt work(it the first time that i have this error), i already have connect an app to MySQL with MySQL connector, and it work perfectly, i didnt understand what happens this time
What i try :

- increase the timeout with the command line
- increase the time with the mysql workbrench
- increase the timeout directly in my code

Comment: if the timeout expires that means there is a connectivity issue between your device and the server

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for your answer, how can i fixe it? ^^"

Comment: it's a connectivity problem.  You need to do some basic network debugging between your device and your server